# Decrypt file that was encrypted using a public key created from storagon.com

Tags: bittorrent, decryption

I recently downloaded a file with BitTorrent application.
The file is encrypted. the file name is :

AAAAAA.rar.{a key with  length of 32}.storagon_encrypted

Does anyone know how I can decrypt the file.

It seems Storagon.com is a file server and has a decryption tool. 
But the site is down for weeks and the decryption tool is not available on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not encrypted. That's just a lie to get you to download and run a trojan.